# MongoDB + Spring MVC

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I have working a project which is combination of Spring MVC and Mongodb .

#### The Database Structure

```
{
     "id": " 12214 -1",
     "eRA": " 12214 -1",
     "agreementId": null,
     "agreementNumber": null,
     "deviceTimestamp": null,
     "tag": null,
     "curentLocation": null,
     "gps": "NO",
     "grps": "NO",
     "logs": {},
     "isRead": "1.0",
     "rptTime": "15:00",
     "salut": "Mr",
     "guestName": "Ritesh Arora",
     "guestCompShortName": "mmi",
     "vehNum": "KL22E2448",
     "chauffName": "baba",
     "rptDate": "40-83-2.01 15:00",
     "rladdr": null,
     "rentalType": "Local Run",
     "addressRL": "Okhla",
     "status": "Received from Carpro"
 }
```

#### Bean Class Structre

```
@Document
public class Agreement {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String eRA;
  private AgreementId agreementId; // /Aggrement No
  private String agreementNumber;
  private String RLAddr; // // RL
  private String Salut; // // Salut
  private String GuestName; // //GuestName ;
  private String GuestCompShortName; // / Company;
  private String VehNum; // / vechileNumber
  private String ChauffName; // / Driver
  private String RentalType; // / RentalType
  private String AddressRL; // / reportingAddress
  private String RptDate; // / RptDate + RptTime reportingDateTime
  private String RptTime; // / RptDate + RptTime reportingDateTime
  private String deviceTimestamp; // ///
  private String tag;
  private String curentLocation;

  @Field("Status")
  private String Status; // // eRAStatus
  private String gps;
  private String type;
  private String grps;
  private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> logs;
  private String isRead;
  private String name;

  public String getType() {
    return this.getStatus();
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

public String getIsRead() {
    return isRead;
}

public void setIsRead(String isRead) {
    this.isRead = isRead;
}

public String geteRA() {
    this.id = this.id.replace("{ \"AgreementNo\" :", "")
            .replace(" \"SubNo\" : ", "").replace("}", "")
            .replace(",", "-");

    return this.id;
}

public void seteRA(String eRA) {
    this.eRA = eRA;
}

public AgreementId getAgreementId() {
    return agreementId;
}

public void setAgreementId(AgreementId agreementId) {
    this.agreementId = agreementId;
}

public String getRLAddr() {
    return RLAddr;
}

public void setRLAddr(String rLAddr) {
    RLAddr = rLAddr;
}

public String getSalut() {
    return Salut;
}

public void setSalut(String salut) {
    Salut = salut;
}

public String getGuestName() {

    return GuestName;
}

public void setGuestName(String guestName) {
    GuestName = guestName;
}

public String getGuestCompShortName() {
    return GuestCompShortName;
}

public void setGuestCompShortName(String guestCompShortName) {
    GuestCompShortName = guestCompShortName;
}

public String getVehNum() {
    return VehNum;
}

public void setVehNum(String vehNum) {
    VehNum = vehNum;
}

public String getChauffName() {
    return ChauffName;
}

public void setChauffName(String chauffName) {
    ChauffName = chauffName;
}

public String getRentalType() {
    String rtype = null;
    if (RentalType == "1" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        rtype = "Local Run";
    } else if (RentalType == "2" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
        rtype = "Out Station";
    } else if (RentalType == "3" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        rtype = "Transfer";
    } else if (RentalType == "4" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
        rtype = "Package";
    } else if (RentalType == "5" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
        rtype = "self Drive";
    } else if (RentalType == "6" || RentalType.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
        rtype = "LTR";
    }
    return rtype;
}

public void setRentalType(String rentalType) {
    RentalType = rentalType;
}

public String getAddressRL() {
    return AddressRL;
}

public void setAddressRL(String addressRL) {
    AddressRL = addressRL;
}

public String getRptDate() {
    String d = RptDate.substring(4, 6) + "-" + RptDate.substring(6, 8)
            + "-" + RptDate.substring(0, 4);
    return d + " " + RptTime;
}

public void setRptDate(String rptDate) {
    RptDate = rptDate;
}

public String getRptTime() {
    return RptTime;
}

public void setRptTime(String rptTime) {
    RptTime = rptTime;
}

public String getDeviceTimestamp() {
    return deviceTimestamp;
}

public void setDeviceTimestamp(String deviceTimestamp) {
    this.deviceTimestamp = deviceTimestamp;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getCurentLocation() {
    return curentLocation;
}

public void setCurentLocation(String curentLocation) {
    this.curentLocation = curentLocation;
}

public String getStatus() {
    String str = null;
    if (Status == "1" || Status.equals("1")) {
        Status = "Received from Carpro";
    } else if (Status == "2" || Status.equals("2")) {
        Status = "Complete Close";
    } else if (Status == "3" || Status.equals("3")) {
        Status = "Recall";
    } else if (Status == "4" || Status.equals("4")) {
        Status = "Accepted";
    } else if (Status == "5" || Status.equals("5")) {
        Status = "Start Journey";
    } else if (Status == "6" || Status.equals("6")) {
        Status = "Reached Pickup location";
    } else if (Status == "7" || Status.equals("7")) {
        Status = "Reached Drop off location";
    } else if (Status == "8" || Status.equals("8")) {
        Status = "Duty completed";
    } else if (Status == "9" || Status.equals("9")) {
        Status = "Expense Pending";
    } else if (Status == "10" || Status.equals("10")) {
        Status = "Didn't used";
    } else if (Status == "11" || Status.equals("11")) {
        Status = "Didn't arrive";
    } else if (Status == "12" || Status.equals("12")) {
        Status = "Break Down";
    } else if (Status == "13" || Status.equals("13")) {
        Status = "Exchange";
    } else if (Status == "14" || Status.equals("14")) {
        Status = "Dispatched to mobile";
    } else if (Status == "15" || Status.equals("15")) {
        Status = "Not Mapped or not delivered to mobilee";
    } else if (Status == "16" || Status.equals("16")) {
        Status = "Not Accepted";
    } else if (Status == "17" || Status.equals("17")) {
        Status = "Start Button Not Pressed";
    } else if (Status == "18" || Status.equals("18")) {
        Status = "Pickup Button not Pressed";
    } else if (Status == "19" || Status.equals("19")) {
        Status = "Closure status not received";
    } else if (Status == "20" || Status.equals("20")) {
        Status = "No GPRS";
    } else if (Status == "21" || Status.equals("21")) {
        Status = "No GPS";
    } else if (Status == "22") {
        Status = "Didn't communicate to fleet";
    }
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public String getAgreementNumber() {

    return agreementNumber;
}

public void setAgreementNumber(String agreementNumber) {
    this.agreementNumber = agreementNumber;
}

public String getId() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Map<String, Map<String, Double>> getLogs() {
    return logs;
}

public void setLogs(Map<String, Map<String, Double>> logs) {
    this.logs = logs;
}

public String getGps() {
    if (this.Status == "21" || this.Status.equalsIgnoreCase("21"))
        return "YES";
    else
        return "NO";
}

public void setGps(String gps) {
    this.gps = gps;
}

public String getGrps() {
    if (this.Status == "20" || this.Status.equalsIgnoreCase("20"))
        return "YES";
    else
        return "NO";
}

public void setGrps(String grps) {
    this.grps = grps;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return RLAddr + " >>> " + Salut + ">>>>>>> " + id + "vdsvsdvs ";
}

}
```

but when is used

```
query1.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Status").is("constant"));
mongoTemplate.find(query1, Agreement.class, "eRA_live_v1");
```

I am getting following Error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/avisweb] threw      exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is   o  org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property status found on com.avis.bean.Agreement!] with root cause
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property status found on com.avis.bean.Agreement!
at   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:228)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:194)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:714)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:605)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createPropertyField(QueryMapper.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:113)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1515)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1506)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:532)
```

Comment: So, let me get that straight: You contract for avis.com, don't bother to explain what you have done so far to solve that problem yourself and expect us to solve it? I am way to polite... But from what I can see, you have a field `status` in the document, and you try to access it via the field name `Status` (note the upper case). Two additional notes: It might be worth reading [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and take a [free class at MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101J/2014_October/about)

Comment: Actually using Status or status both way it will not access on mongotemplate . i think it has not well maped to entity class and collection so plaese suggest me  way to how to mapping bean class when we take database field in upper case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You Make Entity Bean Class You Have @Column Name Where Write The Column Name Which You Declare In To Database And in the intial value you declare any name